# check current language of opencart on footer

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

i want display different message on footer ( /catalog/view/theme/themename/template/common/footer.tpl ) for each respective language of my opencart theme , i tried some code like:

- `$lang = $this->language->get('code');`
- `echo $lang;`
- `$data['lang'] = $this->language->get('code');`
- `$this->data['language_code'] = $this->session->data['language'];`

never of this work;

i want a code like this

```
if ( $language == 'en' ) { echo 'en'; } elseif ( $language == 'DE' ) { echo 'DE'; } .......
```

how i can do this with opencart 2.x ?

Answer (score 1):

Define it in the controller first, else the template won't know it exists.

via the Controller; in catalog/controller/common/footer.php:
**add** the following, beneath *$data['text_newsletter'] = $this->language->get('text_newsletter');*

```
$data['lang'] = $this->language->get('code');
```

Now, you can call it in the template: catalog/view/theme/**your_theme**/common/footer.tpl

```
<?php echo $lang; ?>
```

If you want it to behave based on certain criteria:

```
<?php
    if ($lang =='en'){
         echo'Your default language is English.';
    }elseif($lang =='de'){
         echo'Standardsprache ist Deutsch.';
    }
?>
```